# Using Xenu's Link Sleuth to remove bad 301's / broken page-local links

Tags: redirects, wordpress, cms, sql

I'm trying to fix 2 issues based on the report from Xenu's Link Sleuth.

1. I have numerous 301 Redirects from Wordpress SQL based URLs despite using post name URLs.

Despite using post name based URLs (ie. `abc.com/my-post`), when I run Xenu's Link Sleuth, it shows me a list of redirected URLs, all of which are SQL database related (ie. `abc.com/?p=342`). Is this normal or should I do something to remove/remedy this situation?

2. There are broken page-local links on many of my pages with a format of `abc.com/my-post/#text-5   Anchor occurs multiple times`

The `#text-5` occurs in almost all of them, but how would I fix this? I have no typical anchor links on the page linking to a particular spot on the page. Is this just a theme or Wordpress glitch and should I even be concerned about this?

Comment: It may be a theme based thing, but if a link tester is finding broken pages then you need to fix those. You should also fix unnecessary redirects as well. If you right-click on the red entries in Xenu and choose Properties, you'll see the referring URL and you should visit that URL instead to see if you can find out why that problematic URL is inserted in the first place.

Comment: @Mike I looked at the page source and found the link in the `<head>` of my HTML, which for my Wordpress theme isn't something I ever alter - `<link rel='shortlink' href='http://www.example.com/?p=484' />` Since this link isn't seen on the page anywhere for a user, I wonder if this is just something I can ignore? I'm still wondering about the 2nd part of my question though.

Comment: You might want to pick a different wordpress theme or setup. That link tag is something search engines might try to review. If there are URLs advertised in your HTML that no users (or their browsers) can have direct access to then the URLs should not be listed.

Comment: The WP theme I'm using is Themify - Ultra. Not exactly a small/junky theme, but also not perfect either apparently.